# Aspx page refuses to render

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following short markup.
I try to "view this page in browser" via visual studio 2010, but it fails on timeout.
Can someone see why?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Add.aspx.cs" Inherits="TB.Site.Add" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    <label for="Author">Author</label>
<input type="text" id="Author" runat="server" />
<br />
<label for="Email">Email</label>&nbsp;
<input type="text" id="Email" runat="server" />
<br />
<label for="TextArea1">Text</label>
    <textarea id="TextArea1" cols="20" dir="ltr" name="S1" rows="2"  runat="server"></textarea> 
<br />
    <br />

<label id="output" runat="server"></label>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

code behind is

```
namespace TB.Site
{
    public partial class Add : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you press F5 for debugging?

Comment: Your markup doesn't really interact with the code-behind, so there shouldn't be any problems on this page by itself. Are you doing anything in Global.asax? How have you set up the properties of this project in Visual Studio?

Comment: @jwiscarson other aspx pages in the same project works fine.

Comment: Here's a useful troubleshooting technique: keep removing stuff until it works. In fact, I'd immediately try removing all markup except for `<html><body></body></html>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still don't know what was it.
Opened the same solution on another machine and saw yellow error on the Add.aspx
opened a new aspx and copied componenet by component - and it works.

Answer (score 2):

In a fresh project, your page loads fine.  That leads me to believe you have another bit of code somewhere with the Add page defined, probably in a renamed file.

Do a search for

```
public partial class Add
```

see if it comes up in another file.